# Postgresql WAL cleanups on S3 bucket

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

Our `archive_command` is a script that sends the WAL backups to a remote S3 bucket (Minio) via `curl`. When trying to implement the retention policy on the S3 bucket, how can I safely delete files? I know that I can use `pg_archivecleanup` but that won't work with the remote S3 bucket. I don't want to download all files WALs just to be able to know which ones are safe to delete.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What about expiring them by age?

Comment: Yes currently we are doing that, but it seems like `pg_archivecleanup` is the safer way to go. Just that I can't use it :(